# Relative path not working in specific file but works with absolute path - PHP

Tags: php, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm a newbie in PHP. My project is stored in the folder called 'Remember'. I want to include database.php into the home.php

1. Remember/app/database/database.php
2. Remember/app/logged/home.php

In the home.php file
I have this code

```
require_once('../database/database.php');
```

> Warning: require_once(../database/database.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\allProject\CS50\final_project\Remember\app\logged\home.php on line 12

But if I'm using absolute path, it will work

```
require_once("E:/allProject/CS50/final_project/Remember/app/database/database.php");
```

I wonder why this happen because before this code, there are no problems about the file path

Comment: That's exactly how it works and why you should always use absolute paths

Comment: Make sure the `include_path` setting in php.ini contains `.`, which means the directory containing the script.

Comment: No, DON'T use any include_path. Just always use absolute path built from document root

Comment: As to why, are you calling home.php directly or include it in another file?

Comment: yeah, I'm calling home.php in another file.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't work, since in my code using like  `include("../../app/logged/home.php");` doesn't cause any problem

Comment: relative paths **always** cause problems. Because they are relative. always use only absolute paths, even *relative* to current file. https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths